# Problems setting theme array of view object dynamically

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using [theming](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html) in `Yii2` and was previously doing it via the application config file like this:

```
'view' => [
    'theme' => [
        'pathMap' => [
            '@app/views' => [
                '@app/themes/test',
                '@app/themes/default',
            ],
        ],
        'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/default',
        'basePath' => '@webroot/themes/default',
    ],
],
```

This worked fine; however I needed to change things over and do it dynamically so I tried the below code within a custom file that runs during the bootstrapping process:

```
// Set our current theme
$theme_data['pathMap']['@app/views'][] = '@app/themes/' . Yii::$app->params['settings']['selected_theme'];

// Do we need to add our default theme as a fallback?

if (Yii::$app->params['settings']['selected_theme'] != 'default') {
    $theme_data['pathMap']['@app/views'][] = '@app/themes/default';
}

// Set our base url and base path keys
$theme_data['baseUrl'] = '@web/themes/default';
$theme_data['basePath'] = '@webroot/themes/default';

// Now set the data in our view instance
Yii::$app->view->theme = $theme_data;
```

That file runs during the bootstrapping process as specified above, because of this setting in the application config:

```
'bootstrap' => [
                //....
                'app\base\Settings',
],
```

However now when I try and load the site I get the error:

```
Call to a member function applyTo() on a non-object
```

...which appears to be caused by a call to render a view file.

I have even tried using `Yii::getAlias()` with those settings but got the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps `path_map` in your new config should be `pathMap` like your old config?

Comment: @bishop I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: Your custom file has this line `$theme_data['path_map']`.  Your old config had `'theme' => [ 'pathMap' => [ ... ]]`.  Those keys do not match: `path_map` != `pathMap`.  Perhaps they should.

Comment: Ohhhh.... I see. Well I changed it but still got the same error. I will try again with `getAlias()`.

Comment: @bishop Nope, same error even after changing and trying again with `getAlias()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is what I did:

```
use yii\base\Theme;

// Set our view theme property to a theme instance
Yii::$app->view->theme = new Theme();

// Set our current theme
$path_map['@app/views'][] = '@app/themes/' . Yii::$app->params['settings']['selected_theme'];

// Do we need to add our default theme as a fallback?

if (Yii::$app->params['settings']['selected_theme'] != 'default') {
    $path_map['@app/views'][] = '@app/themes/default';
}

// Update our path map
Yii::$app->view->theme->pathMap = $path_map;

// Set our base url and base path keys
Yii::$app->view->theme->baseUrl = Yii::getAlias('@web/themes/default');
Yii::$app->view->theme->basePath = Yii::getAlias('@webroot/themes/default');
```

Take note that when setting the `basePath` and `baseUrl` properties directly and *not* via the view instance you need to use `getAlias()` so you pass in the correct path/url; whereas `pathMap` states you can use aliases within it.